# Twitter API Rate Limits

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I use the Twitter SDK for iOS (and Android,too). My iOS app pulls some tweets from the Twitter API via network request.

In the documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting and https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) Twitter describes some rate limits for requests and differs them "Per User or Per Application".

My iOS app pulls for example information from the endpoint https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets with "guest authentication" (means: usage "Per Application" - not "Per User") to build a Twitter social wall.

What I don´t understand: What does Twitter mean in this case with rate limit for an *Application*? Does this means single instance of my iOS app on a device has it´s own rate limit for this request *or* does all my total instances of all iOS apps share this rate limit together (because the authentication uses the same fabric-app keys on all devices)?

I´m confused ... can somebody explain this to me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate limits for application authentication are shared by all apps connecting with the same application credentials. Basically, rate limits are applied per access token, as described [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting). You can use the [rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status) endpoint to find out the remaining number of requests your app can make in the current 15-minute window.

Comment: I know your link and wrote it in already in my post. And I read this, but I´m not sure what they call an "app" ... the "fabric application" or one of my mobile apps on the phones: "When using application-only authentication, rate limits are determined globally for the entire application. If a method allows for 15 requests per rate limit window, then it allows you to make 15 requests per window — on behalf of your application. This limit is considered completely separately from per-user limits."

Comment: "Application" refers to the twitter application you registered, named, and created credentials for. Rate limits are tied to the access token. So, for user authentication, each user has unique credentials which get their own rate limit. For application authentication, everyone is using the same access token, so there is one rate limit for everyone combined.